# How can I call image files stored in a class into my form in C#?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, picturebox

I'm designing a small interactive interior map based on static images and using gifs to transition between them, as to simulate 3D movement. The images and gifs are contained within picture boxes. The form uses buttons to trigger the picturebox which holds the specific image files depending on the position. Basically each picturebox is either a wall or used to simulate movement with a gif.

Now I can get this working perfectly by using the following code within the button's click event in my main form:

```
pboxSCREEN.Image = new  Bitmap(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Resources\start2.jpg"));
```

However I would like to use a separate **class** to hold all the image files within variables, and use method calls within the button's click event in my main form to get the images I need to display. The idea is for the separate class to store the "walls" that I need to call in the main form. So far this is what I have in the separate class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TheEldritchTruth
{
public class WallCollection
{
    public Image img1 = null;

    public WallCollection()
    {
        img1 = new Bitmap(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Resources\resident.gif"));
    }

    public Image Img1
    {
        get { return img1; }
        set { img1 = value; }
    }
}
```

}

I'm setting a variable to hold the class in the form by this:

```
  public WallCollection walls;
```

And initializing it in the Load event:

```
WallCollection walls = new WallCollection();
```

My question is - how can I call the method in the separate class from within the button's click event? I've tried several different ways with no luck, so far I have something like this:

```
//FORWARD btn
    public async void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (pos == 0)
        {
            pboxSCREEN.Visible = true;

            pboxSCREEN.Image = walls.Img1;                

            //pBoxItem.Visible = false;
            pos = 1;

        }            
    }
```

I can't get thee images to display by using this logic and get this error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0):

To have image use in `Forward` and `Backward` Buttons, you don't need to have a seperate class. You can use `List<Bitmap>` instead.

In the code bellow, I store all bitmaps int `List<Bitmap> bitmaps`. When you need a bitmap, you call it by the index: `bitmaps[0]` for first bitmap, `bitmaps[1]` for second,...

A code sample:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Bitmap> bitmaps = new List<Bitmap>();
    int pos = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddBitmaps();
        if (bitmaps.Count > 0)
        {
            pboxSCREEN.Image = bitmaps[0];
        }
    }

    void AddBitmaps()
    {
        bitmaps.Add(new Bitmap(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Resources\resident.gif")));
        bitmaps.Add(new Bitmap(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Resources\start2.jpg")));
    }

    public void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (pos > 0 && pos <= bitmaps.Count)
        {
            pos--;
            pboxSCREEN.Visible = true;
            pboxSCREEN.Image = bitmaps[pos];
        }
    }

    public void btnBackward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pos + 1 < bitmaps.Count)
        {
            pos++;
            pboxSCREEN.Visible = true;
            pboxSCREEN.Image = bitmaps[pos];
        }
    }
}
```